# Pushing data into an array in a Json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to push an an object into an array in in a Json file.
To make it simple lets say that my Json looks like this:

```
var JsonObj = {
"elements" : []
}
```

I tried Push() method but it didnt work.
tried also to assign to JsonObj.elements[0]= ...  it also fails.
How can i make it work?

Comment: That's not JSON, it's JavaScript.

Comment: *"I need to push an an object into an array in in a Json file."* You can't really modify a *file* with client side JavaScript. Please provide more information.

Comment: If u target - at re-write file ON server - u have to ajax to back-end (ruby, nodejs, php and etc..) and re-write file in back-end with data from javascript throw ajax

Comment: @FelixKling I do plan to modify a json object locally..

Comment: So you don't actually want to write to a file? You simply want to mutate a **JavaScript** object/array?

Comment: @FelixKling Im getting a json object from a web service. I want to modify this Json and send it back tothe web service. I only have a problem when i try adding data to arrays.

Comment: `JsonObj.elements[0] = 'foo';` will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try that way, it has to work:

```
JsonObj.elements.push(1);
```

FIddle: https://jsfiddle.net/29qa4bfw/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is basic Javascript. nothing to do with Json or jQuery:

```
var jsonObj = {
"elements" : []
};

jsonObj.elements.push(1);
jsonObj.elements.push(1.5);
jsonObj.elements.push("some text");
jsonObj.elements.push({element: "some element"});
```

Here's a jsbin to fool around with: http://jsbin.com/hajale/2/edit